# Junit Testing with Fractions

Tags: java, junit

Im looking for some advice with JUnit testing.

I understand the basics but im not sure with this one. Its testing the Greatest Common Divisor of a Fraction.

```
     // Greatest Common Divisor
public static int gcd(int x, int y) {
    return (y == 0) ? x : gcd(y, x % y);
}
```

And heres the JUnit test.

```
@Test
    public void testGcd() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }
```

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You could start with implementing the unit test. [Here's](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JUnit/article.html) a tutorial.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the question is. I mean, basically you'd test known inputs and outputs, and exercise the conditional.

Comment: Well, think of where this code could conceivably fail.  Does it do a simple gcd?  Does it handle the cases where either or both inputs are zero?  etc, etc.  Write a test-case for each consideration.

Comment: remove the `fail` and replace it with your test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you will need more than one test to see that the function is correct. Each test case should make one assertion about the value returned by `gcd(x,y)`, like this:

```
@Test
public void testGcd111_259() { 
    assertEquals(37, gcd(111, 259));
}
```

You need to include other tests to check that your `gcd` works fine when:

- One of the two numbers is zero
- Both numbers are zero
- The numbers are equal to each other
- One of the two numbers is `1`
- One of the two numbers is a prime
- Both numbers are prime
- The numbers coprime without being prime

Comment: The pair 259 and 111 [is borrowed from here](http://books.google.com/books?id=MsUmAAAAMAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=111%2C259).

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with the wonderful [spock](http://code.google.com/p/spock) testing framework which integrates with JUnit.

```
class GCDTest extends Specification {
    def "greatest common denominator of two numbers"() {
        expect:
            MyMathUtils.gcd(a, b) == c

        where:
            a   | b   | c
            1   | 1   | 1
            2   | 1   | 1
            2   | 2   | 2
            10  | 15  | 5
            111 | 259 | 37
    }
}
```